# C++: Writing a function to find values within a map

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, struct, find

I have a map that looks essentially like this...

Key----------Value

1132-------Name, Artist, Size, Date_Added

1133-------Name2, Artist2, Size2, Date_Added2

1134-------Name3, Artist3, Size3, Date_Added3

I want to write a find() function that takes in two parameters specifically a search string by (name or artist) and then a specific value such as a the actual name of part of the song or the artists first or last name.  The search is for any occurrence of the target in the designated data member.  It needs to also be case and punctuation INSENSITIVE.    If succesful the value of the map is returned.  If unsuccessful then "not found" is returned.  Any assitance on writing this function?

Here is my code so far...

```
MusicEntry MusicLibrary::find(string &search_str, string &value){
     for(elements:search_str){
       elements += tolower(elements);        
    }
    if(elements == "name" || elements == "artist"){

    }
}
```

**In my functions.h**

```
struct MusicEntry{
    string name, artist, date_added;
    long size;

    MusicEntry() = default;
    MusicEntry(string name_str, string artist_str, long size_int, string date_added_str) : 
        name(name_str), artist(artist_str), size(size_int), date_added(date_added_str) {};
    string to_string();
};

struct MusicLibrary{
    map <long, MusicEntry> Music_Map;

    MusicLibrary(string file_name);
    string to_string();
    void insert(MusicEntry Entry);
    MusicEntry find(string &search_str, string &value);

};
```

Comment: That doesn't look like all your code... it looks like you just implemented an iterator and didn't actually try to access the `map` data members and do some comparisons.

Comment: `it->second` will be `MusicEntry`, so what is it you can't manage to do?

Comment: The point of using a <map>, should be that you can do a lookup on the key (using MisicLib.find(key) -- you are trying to do a lookup and a find on the data which is not indexed -- I would suggest you revistt the design.

Comment: I want to implent a search essentially for this program, to search by either name or artist followed by a name of a song or an artist's name.  So...("name","John Mayer")

Comment: Hi Tyler, I agree with Soren's suggestion that it's not very natural to search a map this way.  If you want to proceed, here is my suggestion:  create a new function `bool insensitiveMatch(const string& target, const string& entry)`.  Then, the `find` function can loop over all the `MusicEntry` values in the map, and compare either the `MusicEntry::name` or the `MusicEntry::artist` to the `search_str` , using this new function.  If you have problems, post back.